# `gulp-replace` is only replacing some, but not all, of the targets

Tags: javascript, replace, gulp, gulp-replace

**`gulp-replace` isn't replacing everything that it should.**

I'm trying to replace `<li>`'s and it's only removing some of them. When I add a list item it is successfully removed but the ones in original document are not. This is even true if I copy/paste the `<li>` into a new file.

**test.html** is the source document.

```
<h2>Copied from source:</h2>
<ul>
    <li class="Bullets">Athletics</li>
    <li class="Bullets">Burglary</li>
</ul>

<h2>Entered in Sublime Text 2</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Eos ipsam in dolorum odio!</li>
    <li>Illum asperiores eligendi, iure tempora.</li>
    <li>Reprehenderit blanditiis repudiandae ex eligendi.</li>
</ul>
```

**test.md** is what is outputted. Note that the `<li>`'s that I entered in Sublime Text are removed but the others are not.

```
<h2>Copied from source:</h2>
<ul>
    <li class="Bullets">Athletics</li>
    <li class="Bullets">Burglary</li>
</ul>

<h2>Entered in Sublime Text 2</h2>
<ul>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    Eos ipsam in dolorum odio!</li>
    Illum asperiores eligendi, iure tempora.</li>
    Reprehenderit blanditiis repudiandae ex eligendi.</li>
</ul>
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var replace = require('gulp-replace');
  var dest = require('gulp-dest');

  gulp.task('replace', function(){
    gulp.src(['source/*.html'])
      .pipe(replace('<li>',''))
      .pipe(dest('dest', {ext: '.md'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  });

})();
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another regex answer:

```
.pipe(replace(/<\s*li[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*li>/g, '$1')
```

[Reference](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm?rp=%3C%5Cs*h4%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E(.*%3F)%3C%5Cs*%2F%5Cs*h4%3E&rf=g&me=0&ts=%3Ch4%20class%3D%22sds%22%3EAnd%20more%20...%3C%2Fh4%3E)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `tag` in the `replace` function, `replace` can be called with a **string** or **regex**.

To match all `li` tags you can try to use this `regex`:

```
.pipe(replace(/\<li.+li\>/g, '')
```

Comment: Isn't `'<li>'` a string? I'm doing things like `.pipe(replace('<head>',''))` and that is working?

Comment: @AmazingRando yes, and it's *only replacing some* `<li>` tags